# mfpmath option to MinGW (or even gcc)

Tags: gcc, mingw, sse, avx

Does the `-march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7-avx` or `-march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -mavx` command line options to **MinGW** with the `-mfpmath=sse` command line option (or even with `-mfpmath=both`) enables using of **AVX** instruction for math routines? Note, that `--with-fpmath=avx` from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) does not work (that is "unrecognized option" for recent builds on **MinGW**).

Answer (score 3):

AVX is enabled by either `-march=corei7-avx` or `-mavx`. The `-mtune` option is neither necessary nor sufficient to enable AVX.

A `-mfpmath=avx` does not make any sense, because with this switch you control the generation of scalar floating point code. It makes no difference if you use only one float of a 4 float vector register or only one element of a 8 float vector register. If you have `march=avx` enabled, scalar floating point instructions will use the VEX encoding anyway, which will save a few mov instructions.

Note that on x86_64 `-mfpmath` defaults to SSE, so using this switch is usually not necessary or even harmful if you don't exactly know what you are doing.